# Bootstrap Toggle switch not working on change function - Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I need to make an AJAX call when I press the toggle; the code works without bootstrap switch, but when I load with bootstrap switch the AJAX doesn't work.

View

```
'<input type="checkbox" class="inicioestatus" id="iniciotoggle" idproduccion="'.$row['id'].'" fecha="'.$fechahoy.'" valor="2" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-on-text="Ok" data-off-text="No"></td>'
```

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#iniciotoggle').on('switch-change', function() {
                var idproduccion = $(this).attr('id');
                var fecha = $(this).attr('fecha');
                var valor = $(this).attr('valor');
                // Start AJAX function
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>produccion/actualizarinicio",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {idproduccion:idproduccion, fecha:fecha, valor:valor},
                    success: function(data){
                        //function         

                    }
             });
             // End AJAX function
        });
     });  
</script>
```

I know my problem is the javascript but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Is the "bootstrap switch" you are talking about the example from the BS docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#switches, or is this an external plugin?

Comment: Hello @bgaynor78 already fixed, but i have a problem the id #iniciotoggle is repeat and the code only work with te first one, any idea?

Comment: I'd change your selector for the `.on()` method to look at the class, not the id. So...`$('.inicioestatus').on('switch-change', function() { // stuff });`

Comment: Work, thank you so much! @bgaynor78

Comment: Ey @bgaynor78 the js its taking all the var from the first element, any idea?

Comment: it shouldn't be. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/v8mq3d6r/4/) with as close as I can get to a example. I don't know what library you are using for the switch, so my example is using a plain checkbox, but the the functionality should be the same as what you're doing and I can log the correct values